# Why did Linda steal visiting cards?

Tags: plot-explanation, widows

In Widows (2018), Harry's widow Veronica hands her gangmate Linda a blueprint of a building and she asks her to visit the building. So Linda visits “Bridges | Getty” architect office and shows the desk receptionist a blueprint and asks about the designer of the blueprint. Although hesitant, the receptionist answers her. Meanwhile, Linda steals visiting cards:

[image]

Why did Linda steal visiting cards?

Answer (score 3):

Linda is hoping that the architect who designed the building will have a business card in the card holder, simplifying the task of reaching out to him.

> **Receptionist:** *Wait a minute, let me ask someone.*
>
> [She takes the blueprint and disappears. LINDA eyes the business cards on the reception desk, grabs a handful, and stuffs them into her purse. She walks to the adjacent balcony, tracking the receptionist through the atrium, spotting her having a conversation.
>
> The receptionist returns.]
>
> **Receptionist** (Cont'd): *I'm sorry I can't tell you anything.*
>
> **Linda** (growing desperate): *My boss is interested in having one built just like it.*
>
> [Her desperation kindles something in the receptionist.]
>
> **Receptionist:** *It was designed by Terry Foster*
>
> **Linda:** *Thank you*
>
> Int. Linda's Car - Day
>
> [TERRY FOSTER is not among the cards she has stolen]
>
> **Linda:** *Shit*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Widows: Script](https://thescriptlab.com/wp-content/uploads/scripts/90227-Widows-by-Gillian-Flynn-and-Steve-McQueen.pdf)</sup></sub>